# Arrays within an array is losing it's elements down to the first two

Tags: c, arrays

I'm new to C, since I come from Python, specifying stuff is sorta new to me. So I have this code, and everything seems to be working fine except just one problem, and that's with the array. I have arrays within an array as you can see below. The arrays are losing all their elements but the first two, and I don't know what's happening. I would greatly appreciate it if someone could correct my errors. Thanks in advance.

```
char *checkFirstNumber(long number) {
    int startsDictionaryValue[3][5] = {
        {51, 52, 53, 54, 55},
        {34, 37},
        {4,}
    };
    string startsDictionaryKey[3] = {"AMEX", "MASTERCARD", "VISA"};
    char *strNumber = calloc(sizeof(*strNumber), 17);
    sprintf(strNumber, "%ld", number);
    char *cardName = calloc(sizeof(*cardName), 11);
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
        printf("%d: %d\n", i, ArraySize(startsDictionaryValue[i]));
        for (int x=0; x<ArraySize(startsDictionaryValue[i]); x++) {
            if (startsDictionaryValue[i][x] != 0){
                printf("%d\n", startsDictionaryValue[i][x]);
                char *strValue = calloc(sizeof(*strValue), 3);
                sprintf(strValue, "%d", startsDictionaryValue[i][x]);
                if (match(strNumber, strValue)) {
                    cardName = startsDictionaryKey[i];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return cardName;
}
```

This is the output from the prints within in this function.

```
0: 2
51
52
1: 2
34
37
2: 2
4
```

Without the if statement on line 14, there would be a 0 printed after this 4.
Edit: Sorry I didn't have the ArraySize function on here before, I've just put it down below

```
int ArraySize(int array[]) {
    return sizeof(&array) / sizeof(int);
}
```

Comment: How can we know how or why `ArraySize` is returning the wrong value if we can't see what `ArraySize` does or how it works?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: This is important in C:  arrays carry no sizing information when they get passed to a function.

Comment: Note that all three rows of the array are the same size, 5 integers; the unspecified initializers are zeros.  However, your `ArraySize()` function is passed a pointer, so it always returns 2 on a 64-bit machine where pointers are 8 bytes long and `int` is 4 bytes long.  You simply can't do what you're seeking to do in C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sizeof()` needs to know the size of the array at compile time in order to calculate the length of an array. As it stands, this is impossible with your function (`ArraySize()`), as the size of the array will not be available within the function. In C, arrays passed as arguments to functions decay into pointers, which are simply addresses pointing to the first elements in the arrays. As such, it is impossible for the compiler to determine the size of the array from just this information.

Instead, do the following the loop

```
for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
    int len = sizeof(startsDictionaryValue[i][0])/sizeof(startsDictionaryValue[i]);

    printf("%d: %d\n", i, len);
    for (int x=0; x<len; x++) {
        if (startsDictionaryValue[i][x] != 0){
            printf("%d\n", startsDictionaryValue[i][x]);
            char *strValue = calloc(sizeof(*strValue), 3);
            sprintf(strValue, "%d", startsDictionaryValue[i][x]);
            if (match(strNumber, strValue)) {
                cardName = startsDictionaryKey[i];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This calculation, however, could really be moved outside of the loop, as each iteration will return the same length.

If you wanted to stick with the function approach, you would need to modify `ArraySize()` so that it counted until it found a `0` element in the array; this is similar to what `strlen()` does, but for `int` instead of `char`.

Comment: Ah I see, I'll test this out.

Comment: Note that the array is an array of `int`; `strlen()` doesn't work with such arrays. Also, the data in the first row is not terminated by a zero.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler True, forgot they were `int`. Will adjust accordingly.